# How do you appear offline to friends on Battle.net?

Tags: battle.net

I have a number of friends on my battle.net account. However, sometimes I don't want to appear online to some (or all) of them. Is there a way to be hidden from your friends on battle.net?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The option to appear invisible was [anounced back in 2012](https://worldofwarcraft.com/en-gb/news/10015474) but was missing from Battle.net for a long time and a [2014 tweet](https://twitter.com/CM_Lore/status/440536278858096641) mentioned that it wouldn't be included for some time.

**New Update: It's Here:**
As of October 2017 the option to appear offline is implemented in the beta version of the Blizzard Battle.net app and will come to the standard version later. (There are also other new features like groups and chat channels coming to the app.) See this [announcement](https://news.blizzard.com/en-us/blizzard/21098852/new-social-features-now-in-beta-in-the-blizzard-battle-net-desktop-app) from Blizzard for more details.

(See the [previous revision](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/159432/7) of this answer for some now outdated information.)

Comment: Live version of Diablo III is 2.6, so this promise looks like "soon™" to me :-D I wonder if they actually had this press release written back then...

Comment: You are right, that was a very old post (from 2012-09-20), which I already linked at the start of my answer ... I was fooled because another site (www.wowhead.com) posted it today. I will edit again.

Comment: Appear offline was added! https://news.blizzard.com/en-us/blizzard/21098852/new-social-features-now-in-beta-in-the-blizzard-battle-net-desktop-app

Comment: @walrushelmet: Yes, it seems to be coming finally. For now the feature is only in the beta version of the Battle.Net app. I will update the answer when I have time.

Answer (score 5):

Currently (as unfortunate as this is), there is no option to appear offline to friends which are added to the battlenet list. The only option is to remove them and add them on again later, but this does not really do the job as other networks like skype or the like do it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "other networks like skype or the like do it"?

Comment: @bd33 they typically have a mode that makes it seems like you are actually offline

Comment: Ah, I understand now. When you remove a friend, does it remove you from their list or notify them in any way?

Comment: You are definitely being removed from their list as well; not sure about the notification, though I do believe there is none. Have been playing WoW, Diablo 3 and Hearthstone; in each of those games I have removed people from the list and have been removed as well, and I did not see a notification either way. @ratchet: That is exactly what I meant, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to use Windows firewall to block outgoing TCP access to:

```
12.129.206.134:1119
```

### Step by Step

1. Click **Start**
2. Search for **Windows Firewall with Advanced Security**
3. Select **Outbound Rules**
4. Click **New Rule...**
5. *What type of rule would you like to create?*: **Custom**, click **Next**
6. *Does this rule apply to all programs or a specific program?*: **All programs**, click **Next**
7. *Protocol type*: **TCP**
8. *Remote port*: **Specific Ports**, enter **1119**, click **Next**
9. *Which remote IP address does this rule apply to?*: click **These IP Addresses**, click **Add**
10. **This IP address or subnet**: **12.129.206.134**, click **OK**
11. Click **Next**
12. *What action should be taken when a connection matches the specified conditions?*: **Block the connection**, click **Next**
13. *When does this rule apply?*, all checked, click **Next**
14. *Name*: **Blizzard Battle.net Chat client**
15. Click **Finish**

The IP address of Battle.net chat client may be different for you. But that's what it was for me.

Comment: you should add a way to find out IP address of Battle.net chat client if it's different for everyone.